# Bundle icon missing under iOS XCode 8

Tags: ios, bundle, xcode8

I'm trying to create a new bundle target in Xcode8 for iOS but noticed that there is no option for bundle. There however is one under the macOS section. Is there a reason for this? Should I not be using a bundle for iOS development? Thanks.

Comment: Are you meaning a testing bundle? Look under "Test"

Comment: No, a bundle to put certain xibs so I can use them from a different project file.

Comment: There are no loadable bundles in iOS (in the Mac OS X sense). You can make a framework target.